# Java - Runtime.freeMemory()

Tags: java

I was trying to see usage of Runtime.freeMemory().

Documentation  says it 'Returns the amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine'

I executed a simple program test this. Program below:

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Total memory: " +Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println("Free memory: " +Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    Integer intArr[]= new Integer[10000];
    for(int i =0; i<10000;i++){
        intArr[i] = new Integer(i+500);
    }
    System.out.println("Free memory: " +Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println("sample print :"+ intArr[0]);
    System.out.println("sample print :"+ intArr[5000]);
    System.out.println("sample print :"+ intArr[9999]);
 }  
}
```

Output:

Total memory: 67108864

Free memory: 61822408  < Before allocating 10000 objects>

Free memory: 61822408  < Size remains same even after allocating 10000 objects. why?>

sample print :500

sample print :5500

sample print :10499

Since the objects are created on heap, the 'Free memory' value printed second time should be less than the first output, right?

But it prints same value. Can anyone please explain why it print same value?

Comment: You gotta try something a LOT bigger than 10000 Integer objects to see the difference.

Comment: @CoolBeans - platform and JVM dependent. Running the above code on my machine (Linux + Sun JVM 1.6_22) shows a drop in free memory.

Comment: what OS are you using, and which version of Java? Your code acts as expected on my machine.

Comment: @Brain - OS:Windows XP, JDK -1.6.0_05. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it is not the answer you wanted - but according to the JavaDoc - `freeMemory` returns:

> an **approximation** to the total amount
>   of memory currently available for
>   future allocated objects, measured in
>   bytes.

Just to test it - I took your code and ran twice. Once with the array size set to 10,000 - and once with 100.
I also added another print just after:

```
Integer intArr[]= new Integer[10000];
```

When running with `10,000` - I got the expected result, a decrease of `40,0016 bytes` in free memory just after the array instantiation.

When running with `100` I got the exact same amount of free memory before and after array instantiation - **not** the desired effect.

As most answers already stated - as it is a native method - is JVM dependent and therefore can act differently on any platform.
I'm running on `Windows 7` with the `Eclipse built-in JVM (v3.6)`.

But I think the key word here is - **approximation**.

Answer (score 1):

Memory is allocated from the surrounding operating system in large chunks.   The 10000 objects combined are not large enough to cause an additional allocation.

Comment: That shouldn't be the fact since `freeMemory` should be related to the memory that internally is managed by the JVM itself, not sure about it thou..

Comment: platform and JVM dependent. Running the OP's code on my machine (Linux + Sun JVM 1.6_22) shows a drop in free memory

Answer (score 1):

Just checked bytecode.. the fragment is the following, and it is in the middle of the two `printf`:

```
SIPUSH 10000
ANEWARRAY java/lang/Integer
ASTORE 1
```

So it does actually allocate the array dinamically, and `freeMemory` should return a different value. Since it doesn't do so, I guess it is really platform/version dependent like it has already been pointed out.

For example, on my machine it actually changes:

```
Free memory: 81915960
Free memory: 81353824
```

Just another guess: maybe it depends on the initial heap size parameter of the JVM, so that if the JVM starts with enough heap already ready to be used it doesn't need to allocate it before a certain threshold (it is the `-Xms` setting, you could trying increasing or decreasing it to see if something changes).

Comment: You can save this effort - it's not true.